# jenkins - scm files ignore svn files

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to build my projects with subversion plugin.

When it does check out - it also checks out the .svn files from the subversion.

How can I tell him not to include them?

I don't need them since I simply build the projects from them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a "checkout" in Subversion means that you want the repository working-copy metadata.   It sounds like you should just use a script to export your code from the repo... that will give you a raw copy for compilation.